# Postgres fill id inside json from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table is something like this

transport table:

```
id transportation
1  [{ "driver_id": [1,2], "car_id": 1, "price": 20 }, { "driver_id": [3], "car_id": 2, "price": 20 }]
```

driver table:

```
id name license_number
1  tom  11-22-33
2  ben  22-33-44
3  dan  33-44-55
```

car table:

```
id name      type
1  daihatsu  pick-up
2  toyota    transportation
```

the result expected is like this

```
id transportation
1  [ {"driver_id": [ {"id": 1, "name": "tom", "license_number": "11-22-33" }, 
{"id": 2, "name": "ben", "license_number": "22-33-44" } ], 
"car_id": {"id": 1, "name": "daihatsu", "type": "pick-up"}, "price": 20 }, 
{"driver_id": [ {"id": 3, "name": "dan", "license_number": "33-44-55" } ], 
"car_id": {"id": 2, "name": "toyota", "type": "transportation"}, "price": 20 } ]
```

I want the id from json is get filled by related another table,
is this possible in postgres or I have to use traditional relationship table model?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Yes, that should be "car_id": 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first normalize the transport table so that you can properly join the result to the `car` and `driver` tables. As your result is aggregated on two levels, you will need to chain those aggregations, e.g. using [common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

To normalize the transport data, you can use this:

```
select tp.id as transport_id, 
       (t.item ->> 'car_id')::int as car_id, 
       (dt.driver_id)::int,
       t.item ->> 'price' as price
from transport tp
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(tp.transportation) as t(item)
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(t.item -> 'driver_id') as dt(driver_id)
```

The above assumes that `transportation` is a `jsonb` column (which it should be). If it's just a `json` column, you need to use `json_array_elements()` and `json_array_elements_text()` instead.

The result of the above can then be used to join to the `car` and `driver` table and aggregate the drivers for each car:

```
with normalized_transport as (
  select tp.id as transport_id, 
         (t.item ->> 'car_id')::int as car_id, 
         (dt.driver_id)::int,
         t.item ->> 'price' as price
  from transport tp
    cross join jsonb_array_elements(tp.transportation) as t(item)
    cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(t.item -> 'driver_id') as dt(driver_id)
)
select transport_id,
       to_jsonb(c) as car,
       jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(d)) drivers,
       max(price) as price 
from normalized_transport tp
  join driver d on d.id = tp.driver_id 
  join car c on c.id = tp.car_id
group by transport_id, c;
```

The `max(price)` is necessary because of the `group by`. But as we group by `transport_id` we get the same value for each `transport.id` anyway.

This returns the following result:

```
transport_id | car                                                   | drivers                                                                                                          | price
-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------
           1 | {"id": 1, "name": "daihatsu", "type": "pick-up"}      | [{"id": 2, "name": "ben", "license_number": "22-33-44"}, {"id": 1, "name": "tom", "license_number": "11-22-33"}] | 20   
           1 | {"id": 2, "name": "toyota", "type": "transportation"} | [{"id": 3, "name": "dan", "license_number": "33-44-55"}]                                                         | 20
```

So we now have a list of drivers and the cars they used. In a final step we can now aggregate that to the array you want:

```sql
with normalized_transport as (
  select tp.id as transport_id, 
         (t.item ->> 'car_id')::int as car_id, 
         (dt.driver_id)::int,
         t.item ->> 'price' as price
  from transport tp
    cross join jsonb_array_elements(tp.transportation) as t(item)
    cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(t.item -> 'driver_id') as dt(driver_id)
), drivers as (
  select transport_id,
         to_jsonb(c) as car,
         jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(d)) drivers, 
         max(tp.price) as price
  from normalized_transport tp
    join driver d on d.id = tp.driver_id 
    join car c on c.id = tp.car_id
  group by transport_id, c
)
select transport_id, 
       jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('car_id', car)||
                 jsonb_build_object('driver_id', drivers)||
                 jsonb_build_object('price', price))
from drivers
group by transport_id;
```